# Firebase filter list of products base on list of id

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I am creating an app and this problem is giving me a headache for some time
I want to filter a product node base on array of ids that is on another node in the firebase.
I tried with query but query only shows an object
When I try otherwise it shows nothing.
[image: Node 1]
[image: Node 2]
i want to get the ids in node1 and use to filter in node2

[node1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8TDK.png)
[node2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7mOw.png)

I do not know what else to do
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

All You have to do is get Id from Node 1 and then use Nested Query for node 2 with in First query. and get Its Id by using `orderbyKey()` or  `orderByChild("id").equals(key)`

```
mdatabaseRef.child("item").orderBykey().equals(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override     
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
  getValue(value);
   }

private void getValue(String key){
     mdatabaseRef.child("product").orderBykey().equals(key).SingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override     
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String key = child.getKey();
           Object object = postsnapshot.getValue(Object.class);;
             }
```